# xps 7390 system hung overnight (task: PID blocked for more than 120 seconds)

Tags: gnome, usb, kernel, log, xps

I have left my laptop in screen-locked state (Super+L) overnight, and recently noticed an increasing frequency of finding it hung in the morning. I'm pasting part of the log here. A longer version can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/R75iX8wP

One can notice that everything seems to be fine until ~07:05:00. Then the system froze. I suspect it's because of the driver of my WiFi card but not sure. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Linux 5.4.0-39-generic x86_64, xps 7390 2-in-1. I'm new to the system log. I wonder how I can verify this or find the faulty process. Any input would be appreciated!

```
Jul 02 06:27:25 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:27:25 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:28:50 bear-cave canonical-livepatch[1276]: Client.Check
Jul 02 06:28:50 bear-cave canonical-livepatch[1276]: Checking with livepatch service.
Jul 02 06:28:50 bear-cave canonical-livepatch[1276]: Updated last-check.
Jul 02 06:28:50 bear-cave canonical-livepatch[1276]: No updates available at this time.
Jul 02 06:28:50 bear-cave canonical-livepatch[1276]: No payload available.
Jul 02 06:29:30 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:29:30 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:29:51 bear-cave pkexec[91511]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Jul 02 06:29:51 bear-cave pkexec[91511]: bear: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/bear] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jul 02 06:31:36 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:31:36 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:32:00 bear-cave PackageKit[90190]: daemon quit
Jul 02 06:32:00 bear-cave systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 06:33:41 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:33:41 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:35:46 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:35:46 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:37:51 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:37:51 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:39:14 bear-cave systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Jul 02 06:39:17 bear-cave dbus-daemon[1189]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.414' (uid=0 pid=92071 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto" label="unconfined")
Jul 02 06:39:17 bear-cave systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Jul 02 06:39:17 bear-cave PackageKit[92074]: daemon start
Jul 02 06:39:17 bear-cave dbus-daemon[1189]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jul 02 06:39:17 bear-cave systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Jul 02 06:39:20 bear-cave systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 06:39:20 bear-cave systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul 02 06:39:56 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:39:56 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:41:50 bear-cave pkexec[92327]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Jul 02 06:41:50 bear-cave pkexec[92327]: bear: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/bear] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jul 02 06:42:01 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:42:01 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:44:06 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:44:06 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:44:23 bear-cave PackageKit[92074]: daemon quit
Jul 02 06:44:23 bear-cave systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 06:46:11 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:46:11 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:48:17 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:48:17 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:50:22 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:50:22 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:52:27 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:52:27 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:54:33 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:54:33 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:55:55 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Home': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:55:56 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Work': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:55:58 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'zlwang@vt.edu': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:55:58 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Default': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:55:59 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Holidays in United States': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:56:01 bear-cave gnome-calendar[10842]: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Contacts': Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/caldav.googleapis.com/quotas?project=44438659992
Jul 02 06:56:39 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:56:39 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 06:58:45 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 06:58:45 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 07:00:50 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 07:00:50 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 07:01:01 bear-cave CRON[93201]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user bear by (uid=0)
Jul 02 07:01:01 bear-cave CRON[93202]: (bear) CMD (/home/bear/Code/scripts/rclone-cron.sh)
Jul 02 07:02:55 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 07:02:55 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 07:04:32 bear-cave kernel: usb 2-3.2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jul 02 07:04:32 bear-cave kernel: r8152 2-3.2:1.0 enx3448edba014d: Using pass-thru MAC addr xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Jul 02 07:04:58 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:04:59 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:00 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:00 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:00 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 07:05:00 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 07:05:01 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:02 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:06 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:07 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:07 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:08 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:09 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:10 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:16 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:17 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:18 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:19 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:20 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:26 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:27 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:28 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:29 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:30 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:36 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:37 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:38 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:39 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:40 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:46 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:47 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:48 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:49 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:50 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:56 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:57 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:05:59 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:00 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:01 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:11 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:12 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:16 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:17 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:18 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:24 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:25 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:26 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:27 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:28 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:34 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:35 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:36 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:37 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:38 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:44 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:45 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:47 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:48 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:49 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:55 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:56 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:57 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:58 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:06:59 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:05 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:05 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
Jul 02 07:07:05 bear-cave kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: killing stalled connection 7c:6d:62:40:36:fa
Jul 02 07:07:06 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:07 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:08 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:09 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:15 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:16 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:17 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:18 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:19 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:25 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:26 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:27 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:28 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:29 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:35 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:37 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:38 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:39 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:40 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:46 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:47 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:48 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:49 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:50 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:56 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:57 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:58 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:07:59 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:08:00 bear-cave geoclue[1672]: Scanning of WiFi networks failed: Timeout was reached
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: INFO: task NetworkManager:1190 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:       Tainted: G         C        5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: NetworkManager  D    0  1190      1 0x00000000
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  schedule+0x42/0xb0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x182/0x4f0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? kmalloc_large_node+0x88/0xa0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x259/0x320
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  mutex_lock+0x2e/0x40
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  rtnl_lock+0x15/0x20
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  nl80211_dump_scan+0x34/0x160 [cfg80211]
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __alloc_skb+0x98/0x1d0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_dump+0x18b/0x390
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __netlink_dump_start+0x191/0x200
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_family_rcv_msg+0x3e9/0x470
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? nl80211_dump_survey+0x2c0/0x2c0 [cfg80211]
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? do_sys_poll+0x480/0x520
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? copyout+0x2c/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_rcv_msg+0x4c/0xa0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? genl_family_rcv_msg+0x470/0x470
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_rcv_skb+0x50/0x120
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_unicast+0x187/0x220
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_sendmsg+0x222/0x3e0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ____sys_sendmsg+0x212/0x280
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ___sys_sendmsg+0x88/0xd0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? futex_wait+0xe8/0x260
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? get_futex_key+0x30c/0x3b0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? futex_wake+0x8b/0x180
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __fget_light+0x57/0x70
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __sys_sendmsg+0x5c/0xa0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f1c24fa612d
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: Code: Bad RIP value.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fff9531cc10 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055b7a8e6e840 RCX: 00007f1c24fa612d
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fff9531cc60 RDI: 000000000000000b
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RBP: 00007fff9531cc60 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000001000
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: R10: 000055b7a8e40010 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 000055b7a8e6e840
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: R13: 000055b7a8e6e980 R14: 00007fff9531d120 R15: 000055b7a8f105e0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: INFO: task wpa_supplicant:1234 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:       Tainted: G         C        5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: wpa_supplicant  D    0  1234      1 0x00000000
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? enqueue_task_fair+0x173/0x470
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  schedule+0x42/0xb0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x182/0x4f0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  mutex_lock+0x2e/0x40
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  rtnl_lock+0x15/0x20
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  nl80211_pre_doit+0x104/0x1b0 [cfg80211]
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_family_rcv_msg+0x1a5/0x470
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_rcv_msg+0x4c/0xa0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? genl_family_rcv_msg+0x470/0x470
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_rcv_skb+0x50/0x120
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_unicast+0x187/0x220
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  netlink_sendmsg+0x222/0x3e0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ____sys_sendmsg+0x212/0x280
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ___sys_sendmsg+0x88/0xd0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? sock_do_ioctl+0x47/0x140
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __check_object_size+0x4d/0x150
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? _copy_to_user+0x2c/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? sock_ioctl+0x24f/0x3c0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __fpu__restore_sig+0x4a7/0x600
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_setsockopt+0xae/0x2c0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  ? aa_sk_perm+0x43/0x170
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __sys_sendmsg+0x5c/0xa0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f0c84a025b7
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: Code: Bad RIP value.
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffddd1be4c8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005654472705b0 RCX: 00007f0c84a025b7
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffddd1be500 RDI: 0000000000000006
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: RBP: 00005654472a0b80 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007f0c84acab80
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: R10: 00007ffddd1be5d4 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00005654472704c0
Jul 02 07:08:07 bear-cave kernel: R13: 00007ffddd1be500 R14: 00007ffddd1be5d4 R15: 00005654472bc170
```